# how to connect generated time dimension with datetime field, ssas

Tags: ssas

I have a datetime field in my fact table, and I want to group and filter by it, so I created a time dimension and ssas generated a table for it that has a date without time primary key. 
What is the right way to connect this generated table to my field, create a view and calculate there additional date with empty time? or there are any other more simple way, maybe using some hierarchies or something? Sorry for probably very simple question its just my second day with analysis servises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you fill your fact table. The usual way to this is in the ETL process.

You have a time dimension `DIM_Date`
With the columns `Date_ID`, `Year`, `Month`, `Weekday`

Then you should have a fact table `FACT_Sales`
With the columns `Date_ID`, `Product_ID`, `Customer_ID`, `value`

When filling the fact table with your ETL-Tool. Let's assume it is SSIS. You do a lookup in the date dimension and set the surrogate key in the facts (`Date_ID`) correspondingly.

If the tables are allready there. You can use a computed column in the SSAS Data Source View and set your foreign key relationship via drag and drop.